<Link> always push to https
I am using Next.js 14.2  app router.
in one of my pages i am using
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Login() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = new URL(
      "http://blahid/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&blahblahblah/callback"
    );
    // You can also modify the URL here if needed
    router.push(url.toString()); 
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid items-center h-[60vh] mx-auto w-[600px]">
      <button
        className="border shadow-md text-center py-4 px-8 w-[180px] mx-auto"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Giriş Yap
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

however since application use SSL it always went to https://blahid/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&blahblahblah/callback   instead of http://blahid/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&blahblahblah/callback
what i can do so that it will go to http://blahid/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&blahblahblah/callback
The OAuth application is within our company intranet, i tried to achieve it with plain  <a href="http://blablabla...">Go</a>  however no success, still tries to go to https.

Do you want the link to take the user to a completely different page from your current app? If so, why not just use <a href={...}> instead of an event handler to begin with?

What kind of OAuth provider are you using there, that doesn't support HTTPS? Is this some kind of local test setup only? "In the wild", on the actual internet, handling something this sensitive over unencrypted HTTP, would be an absolute no-go.

OAuth is custom provider from company Intranet.  I wonder is there any way to succeed it?  i as well try to use     however still it goes to https .

Since my application is just started, i will convert it to Laravel, as i see Next.js is overhyped with lots of limitations.
